# HSSFCell toString return double vlaue insted of string

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi all I am a beginner in java. I am creating an application for my android phone where I have to read excel file, for this I am using POI. My code look like below

```
    Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
    String phone_no = null;
    String message =null;
    int cell=0;
        while(rowIter.hasNext()){
            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();                
            cell=0;
            while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();

                if(cell==0){
                    phone_no=myCell.toString();                     
                }
                 else if(cell==1){
                    message=myCell.toString();                        

            }
          cell++;
        }    
      }
```

My excel sheet contain phone numbers on first column and messages on second column. When I run the code I am getting phone_num as 1.23456789E9 I need it like 1234567890. But in the case of message I am getting the full string to my variable as I given to excel.

Thanaks in advance....

Comment: I think you'll have to change the excel cell type before fetching info

Comment: try _myCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)_ before fetching

Comment: anybody home? did you try it?

Comment: Hi Bhavik Shah it,s working now. I haven't read the reference manual properly. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is some logical error in your code -

```
cell = 0;
while(cellIter.hasNext()){

    if(cell == 0) {

    }

    if(cell == 1) {

    }
```

Second of all, don't just blindly call `toString` method, read the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html).

Comment: Yes it is a logical error I agree the second "if" should be "elseif" or "else". Thanks for pointing my mistake...

Comment: @Haris: No, `cell = 0` is the problem. After that `cell` is neve going to be 1.

Comment: Yes I mistaken while posting code. But I had done it on my code. I will edit my post.